# DataFrame manipulation with groupby() function- filtering by specific data pointsata values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH3n1.png)

I'd like to display the number of people who are single with management positions that do and do not own their own homes, in a series. I currently have the following code:

```
df['housing'].groupby([df['marital'], df['job']]).value_counts()
```

However this is currently counting the number of homeowners/non-homeowners per job and marital status. I'm only concerned with the single people with management positions.

How can I apply a filter to the resulting series so it only shows the data I am interested in?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions please paste in sample data as pandas dataframe, dictionary, or at least raw data instead of linking to a picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083000/pandas-groupby-with-conditional-formula)

Comment: @SarahSawyer `pd.DataFrame()` is best, but as a dictionary or printed output works, too. Check out these pages for help getting started: [MCVE], [ask], [help]

Comment: @k_n_c Thank you, I am new to SO so I wasn't sure how to enter the dataframe. It's also very large

Comment: @SarahSawyer That's the "minimal" part of minimal reproducible example. Usually five or six rows are suggested unless more are required to reproduce an error or situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `query`:

```
df.query('job=="management" and marital=="single"')['housing'].value_counts()
```

Or you can use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['job'].eq('management') & df['marital'].eq('single'),
       'housing'].value_counts()
```

**Note** your approach can also work if you slice the data afterward:

```
(df['housing'].groupby([df['marital'], df['job']])
   .value_counts()
   .loc[('single','management')]
)
```

Comment: @QuangHoang Can explain a bit more about how the tuple is working in the `.loc` with the `groupby`/`value_counts`?

Comment: @k_n_c see more details [in the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). In short, you can slice MultiIndex with tuples.